# Passing methods as parameters on a deserialized form with no ClassType

Tags: delphi, serialization, methods

I'm effectively trying to deserialize a form.

One of the objects on the serialized form has a method which takes a series of events as parameters.

Now since I don't have the class type of the object when I'm deserializing, I have a method on the object doing the deserialization called AddMethod which is declared like this:

```
procedure TMyDeserializer.AddMethod(ControlName, EventName: String;
  MethodAddr: Pointer);
var
    TargetControl : TControl;
    Method : TMethod;
begin
    if Not Assigned(TempForm) then
        Exit;
    if TempForm.Name = ControlName then
        TargetControl := TempForm
    else
        TargetControl := TempForm.FindChildControl(ControlName);

    if Assigned(TargetControl) then
    begin
        Method.Code := MethodAddr;
        Method.Data := TargetControl;
        SetMethodProp(TargetControl, EventName, Method);
    end;
end;
```

So that I can poke subroutines into the various controls as I deserialize them, The problem is I need to add events as a list of parameters (not to a control). e.g.

```
SetUpEvents(EventHandler1:TNotifyEvent;EventHandler2:TNotifyEvent);
```

Where EventHandler1 and EventHandler2 are defined somewhere in code as

```
Procedure EventHandler1(Sender:TNotifyEvent);  
begin
    // Do something
end;
```

These are not methods but stand alone subroutines.

When I'm assigning these to objects the subroutine doesn't need to be part of an object as the AddMethod procedure handles it with a call like

```
MyDeserializerInstance.AddMethod('Button1','OnClick',@EventHandler1);
```

This works for standard event handlers, such as Button1.OnClick but not if I want to do

```
Procedure SetUpButton1Click(Method: TNotifyEvent)
begin
    TButton(MyDeserializerInstance.TempForm.FindChildControl('Button1')).OnClick = Method;
end;
```

The problem is I can't pass the subroutine as a method to the example Set Up Procedure.

The form being created isn't declared in an interface and is entirely defined by the file it is read from as well as a few stand alone routines in code.

So I suppose the question is how do turn a subroutine into a method at run time (after creating the object it is supposed to be part of), and if I can't do that how do I pass the subroutines in code as parameters in another method?

So far I've tried casting a TMethod as the correct event type and filling in the .Data as the TempForm. It called the correct method but it scrambled the parameters.

Delphi version is 2007

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not just using the built in DFM deserialization, which takes care of assigning event handlers for you?

Comment: It's rare that a handler for an object's event will belong to that same object, but that's the relationship you've hard-coded in AddMethod. Usually, the handler belongs to the component's owner. The exception is when the event belongs to the form itself. Notice how your button's OnClick handler is a method of the form, not the button. You need *four* parameters to that function since there's no guarantee that Method.Data should be equal to TargetControl. Pass the entire method pointer, not just the code portion.

Comment: @Rob: What would the Method.Data contain for Method1 if it's not of object? or should it be always be the TempForm?

Comment: @Mason, I don't think there's a particular reason that states "wow that's a really good idea", I guess it would be more flexible not having a class definition for the form, and it would be nice to change the form layout at run time. The initial idea was to create popup's which grabbed some information and returned it a StringList with ControlName=Value and now it's more... how far can we go with this?

Comment: I think some of the confusion about this question comes from your misuse of the term *method*. Methods are always "of object"; if they weren't, then they wouldn't be methods. For the generic term, say *subroutine*.

Comment: @Rob: Updated to use subroutine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-static class methods have a hidden `Self` input parameter that is filled in when the method is called.  That is what the `TMethod.Data` field corresponds to.  In order to use a standalone procedure as a handler for an event that expects a class method, the procedure must have an extra parameter defined to represent the `Self` parameter so the value of `TMethod.Data` has somewhere to go, ie:

```
procedure Button1ClickHandler(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject);
begin 
  // Do something 
end; 

MyDeserializerInstance.AddMethod('Button1', 'OnClick', @Button1ClickHandler);
```

Your AddMethod() implementation is assigning the TargetControl as the `TMethod.Data` value, so the `Self` and `Sender` parameters above will end up pointing at the same object at runtime, but that is OK.

Without the explicit `Self` parameter defined, that explains why your parameters are getting "scrambled" when the procedure called at runtime.  The hidden `Self` value is being assigned to the `Sender` parameter, and the real `Sender` value is being ignored.

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely. If I add the Self parameter and get the DeserializationInstance to return a TMethod with the TempForm as the Data then I can cast the result as any event e.g. a NavBeforeEvent to pass in as parameters

Comment: Assigning the TempForm to the TMethod.Data is not a requirement for the event handler to work in general. It simply means you will have access to both the TempForm object and the TargetControl object as parameters to the event handler (you can also use GetParentForm(Sender) to get the TempForm object from the TargetControl Sender as well).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong but I don't believe there is a way to create a type definition at runtime in native Delphi. Delphi's RTTI just doesn't handle this yet.

The two scenarios that come to mind for object serialization are persistence and IPC. (There may be more that I haven't thought of).

Delphi's DFM serialization would be an example of persistence. If you look at a dfm you'll notice it isn't defining methods at all. It's simply assigning event handlers to properties expecting an event handler. Both the handlers and the properties are defined at design time using normal type definitions.

If your intent is IPC(whether on the same machine or a remote one) there are already existing frameworks for accomplishing this. ([RemObjects](http://www.remobjectssdk.com/delphi.aspx) comes to mind)

Answer (score 0):

You don't "make a method" at run time. That would amount to compiling new code. The methods that you assign to various event properties need to already exist.

Furthermore, you can't "add events." The object you're deserializing already has events. You defined them when you wrote the class declaration in your Delphi code. You can't add new event properties to a class after it's been compiled.

It appears that what you're really saying is that you have a *standalone procedure* that you happen to have named `Method1`, and you want to pass it as a `TNotifyEvent` parameter when you call `SetUpMethods`.

That's the wrong way to go. That `Method1` procedure isn't a method, despite its name, so you mustn't use it where a method is required. Change that declaration so it *belongs to a class*, and then it will be a method.

If you don't want to have to instantiate the class that the method belongs to, that's fine — you can declare it as a *class method* instead:

```
class procedure TSomeClass.Method1(Sender: TNotifyEvent);
```

I encourage you to change the declaration of `AddMethod` so that the last parameter is of type `TMethod`. Then you're sure to have both the code and data portions of the method pointer. Right now, you're assigning the data portion based on the object whose event property you're assigning, but as I mentioned in my comment, it's rare for that relationship to exist, especially now that the method belongs to an entirely unrelated class (`TSomeClass` in my example). The value of the `TMethod.Data` field becomes the `Self` value when the method gets called. It's your responsibility to ensure that the value you store in that field is of a compatible type for the class the code belongs to.

Comment: if TMethod.Data becomes self, surely TMethod.Data would become the TempForm?

Comment: No, because you are not assigning TempForm to the TMethod.Data field, you are assigning the TargetControl instead.  Thus, the TargetControl will become its own Self for the event handler (which is a duplicate, since the event's Sender parameter will already point at the same TargetControl).